# How to count the unique rows after aggregating to array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Trying to solve the problem in a read-only manner.

My table (answers) looks like the one below:

```
|    user_id     |    value    |   
+----------------+-------------+
|       6        |    pizza    |       
|       6        |    tosti    | 
|       9        |    fries    | 
|       9        |    tosti    |
|      10        |    pizza    | 
|      10        |    tosti    |
|      12        |    pizza    |
|      12        |    tosti    |
|      13        |    sushi    |  -> did not finish the quiz.
```

NOTE: the actual table has 15+ different possible values. (Answers to questions).

---

I've been able to make create the table below:

```
|    value arr   |     count    |  user_id  |   
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
|  pizza, tosti  |       2      |     6     |
|  fries, tosti  |       2      |     9     |
|  pizza, tosti  |       2      |     10    |*
|  pizza, tosti  |       2      |     12    |*    
|     sushi      |       1      |     13    |
```

I'm not sure if the * rows show up in my current query (DB has 30k rows and 15+ value options). The problem here is that "count" is counting the number of answers and not the number of unique outcomes.

Current query looks a bit like:

```
select string_agg(DISTINCT value, ',' order by value) AS value, user_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT value)
FROM answers
GROUP BY user_id;
```

---

Looking for the unique answer combinations like the table shown below:

```
|    value arr   | count unique |   
+----------------+--------------+
|  pizza, tosti  |       3      |       
|  fries, tosti  |       1      |
|     sushi      |       1      | --> Hidden in perfect situation.
```

Tried a bunch of queries, both written and generated by tools. From super simplified to quite complex, I keep ending up with the answers being count instead of the unique combination accros users.

If this is a duplicate question, please re-direct me to it. Learned a lot these last few days, but haven't been able to find the answer yet.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need. Your almost there.

```
select t1.value, count(1) From (
  select string_agg(DISTINCT value, ',' order by value) AS value, user_id
  FROM answers
  GROUP BY user_id) t1
group by t1.value;
```

Comment: You're my hero of the week! Added "WHERE (((answers.question_id) IN (5,9,11,12,13,15,17)))" and it worked like a charm! (The where part, wasn't in my question, so you answered what i'd asked!). I'm unhappy for the client that I asked it after 2 days of trying (really new to SQL) and I'm happy that I waited. Only parts of your query I understand, and I'll dive deeper once I got the time. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can try (this is for SQL Server):

```
select count(*), string_agg(value, ",")
within group (order by value) as count_unique
from answers
group by string_agg(value, ",")
```

Comment: Using the dataclip function in heroku on a postgresql database. Even after i've changed "," to ',' it didn't work somehow (while I've tried similiar queries that did work). Thanks for your input!